# LINUX CP: I need to copy all files from one directory to another without copying any sub-directories

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, directory, cp

I need to copy files from one directory to another without copying any sub-directories. The number and name of sub-directories is dynamic so I cannot "--exclude" specific directories or use the "-r" option. How can I exclude all sub-directories?

CODE1:

```
cp '/media/lm1/My Passport/OneDrive/Music/Yes/*.*' '/home/lm1/Music/Archive'
```

RESULT1:

```
p: cannot stat '/media/lm1/My Passport/OneDrive/Music/Yes/*.*': No such file or directory
```

CODE2:

```
cp '/media/lm1/My Passport/OneDrive/Music/Yes/*' '/home/lm1/Music/Archive'
```

RESULT2:

```
p: cannot stat '/media/lm1/My Passport/OneDrive/Music/Yes/*': No such file or directory
```

CODE3:

```
cp '/media/lm1/My Passport/OneDrive/Music/Yes' '/home/lm1/Music/Archive'
```

RESULT3:

```
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory '/media/lm1/My Passport/OneDrive/Music/Yes'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glob patterns (the wildcard `*.*`) don't work within quotes, but you can move the glob outside the quotes like so:

```
cp '/media/lm1/My Passport/OneDrive/Music/Yes/'*.* '/home/lm1/Music/Archive'
```

Comment: Interpolating is indeed something related to double quotes, but it is not what you have presented.  And what you have presented would work equally well with if the double quotes were replaced with apostrophes / single quotes.

Comment: Very true - I'll edit to correct the wording

Answer (score 2):

Try `cp /media/lm1/My\ Passport/OneDrive/Music/Yes/* /home/lm1/Music/Archive` instead.

Using quotes stops the shell expansion, so instead escape the space character.

Comment: This would work, but issue an error message for any directory the asterisk expands to.